# C# No implicit conversion to inherited type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm hoping someone can explain this to me as I'm confused about it. I have a series of inheritance amongst my classes and interfaces, with a factory to instantiated the correct object. However, I am getting a *Cannot implicitly convert type 'Conn' to IConn. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

Here is an trimmed down version of the code.

```
public abstract class Id
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Id_SourceId
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
}

public interface IConn<T> where T : Id
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetIds();
}

public abstract class Conn<T> : IConn<T> where T : Id_SourceId{ ... }

public class A_Id_SourceId : Id_SourceId{ ... }
public class B_Id_SourceId : Id_SourceId{ ... }

public class ConnA : Conn<A_Id_SourceId > { ... }
public class ConnB : Conn<B_Id_SourceId > { ... }

public IConn<Id_SourceId> Create(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        return new ConnA(); //<-- Error here
    else
        return new ConnB(); //<-- And here
}
```

From what I can see `ConnA` is of type `Conn<A_Id_SourceId>` which in turn (doing a maths type substitution) is of type `IConn<A_Id_SourceId>` and again, is of type `IConn<Id_SourceId>`.

I realise an explicit cast (`return (IConn<Id_SourceId>)(new ConnA())`) would resolve it, but I think its rather ugly, and the cast would be slow (from what I understand). But also I want to understand why it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Conn<A_Id_SourceId> does not inherit from Conn<Id_SourceId>, the same way List<string> does not inherit from List<object>

Comment: [Covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) *may* be able to help out here.

Comment: `Conn<T> : IConn<T> where T : Id_SourceId` is invalid declaration, because `IConn<T>` is restricted to `Id`, but there is no relation between `Id` and `Id_SourceId`. Maybe `Id_SourceId` should inherit `Id`?

Comment: Fixing typos and compile errors, as well as making `IConn` covariant, like `IConn<out T>` will solve the error

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast responses. As a few people mentioned, PavelAnikhouski Damien_The_Unbeliever and the accepted answer, had mentioned this was resolved by making the interface covariant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic arguments, by default, do not participate in inheritance hierarchies, as doing so would break type safety, however, as your `IConn<T>` interface only returns objects of type `T`, and doesn't require them as arguments, you can make the [interface covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces), by adding the `out` keyword:

```
public interface IConn<out T> : where T : Id
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetIds();
}
```

By doing so, the compiler is satisfied that more derived generic types can safely be used:

```
public IConn<Id_SourceId> Create(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        return new ConnA(); //<-- Now fine
    else
        return new ConnB(); //<-- Also fine
}
```

---

If your wondering why this is the case, maybe this example will clarify.

Imagine `IConn<T>` was invariant, and had a method that accepted `Id` objects:

```
public interface IConn<T> : where T : Id
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetIds();
    void AddId(Id id);
}
```

And `Conn<T>` was implemented like this:

```
public class Conn<T> : IConn<T>
{
    private List<T> ids = new List<T>();
    public void AddId(T id) => ids.Add(id);
}
```

And you used `ConnA` in place of `IConn<Id_SourceId>`:

```
IConn<Id_SourceId> connA = new ConnA();

B_Id_SourceId sourceB = new B_Id_SourceId();

// B_Id_SourceId inherits from Id_SourceId

connA.AddId(sourceB); // Tries to add a `B_Id_SourceId` to a list of `A_Id_SourceId`!
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. I could see that it was possible to add, as in your example, the wrong type and I thought there would be a way to resolve it but couldn't work out how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Conn<A_Id_SourceId> does not inherit from Conn<Id_SourceId>, the same way List< String> does not inherit from List< object>

you can add a non-generic interface IConn in this way:

```
public abstract class Id
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Id_SourceId
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
}

public interface IConn {
    IEnumerable<Id> GetIds();
}

public interface IConn<T> : IConn where T : Id
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetIds();
}

public abstract class Conn<T> : IConn<T> where T : Id_SourceId{ 
   public IEnumerable<Id> IConn.GetIds() {
        return this.GetIds().Cast<Id>();
   }

   public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetIds();
}

public class A_Id_SourceId : Id_SourceId{ ... }
public class B_Id_SourceId : Id_SourceId{ ... }

public class ConnA : Conn<A_Id_SourceId > { ... }
public class ConnB : Conn<B_Id_SourceId > { ... }

public IConn Create(bool val)
{
    if (val)
        return new ConnA(); //<-- Error here
    else
        return new ConnB(); //<-- And here
}
```