# Can't add generic Interface to List with same constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I'm struggling with generics and don't really know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my example:

```
public class Repository // Base-class for all repositories
{
    public virtual int GetStatus()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`Repository` is just a base class.

```
public class CarRepository : Repository // base-class for all car repositories
{
    private object dataSource;

    public override int GetStatus()
    {
        return dataSource.GetHashCode(); // dummy
    }

    public virtual int GetPrice(string carName)
    {
        if (carName.Equals("BMW", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
            return 100;
        }

        return 50;
    }
}
```

`CarRepository` simply provides basic methods to interact with cars.

```
public class HttpCarRepository : CarRepository // loads the car data from REST Api
{
    private dynamic httpClient; // just as an example
    public override int GetStatus()
    {
        return httpClient.IsConnected();
    }

    public override int GetPrice(string carName)
    {
        return httpClient.GetAsync("/rest/car/BMW").Result;
    }
}
```

There might also be an `DataBaseCarRepository` that loads the data from a database. You get the point.

That's for the setup.

Now, I want to cache the results. To keep it generic, I've created this construct:

```
public interface ICache<TRepo> // Basic Cache Interface
    where TRepo : Repository
{
    TRepo Repository { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CarCache : CarRepository, ICache<CarRepository> 
{
    public CarRepository Repository { get; set; }
    private dynamic cache;

    public CarCache(CarRepository repo)
    {
        this.Repository = repo;
    }

    public override int GetPrice(string carName)
    {
        if (!this.cache.Contains(carName)) {
            this.cache.Add(carName, this.Repository.GetPrice(carName));
        }

        return cache[carName];
    }
}
```

`CarCache` derives from the base class `CarRepository` to make it possible to override the methods. It also implements `ICache<T>` which provides a reference to an actual
implementation of `CarRepository`, such as `HttpCarRepository`.

Now I want to add the `CarCache` to a list of caches.

```
public class Manager
{
    public List<ICache<Repository>> Caches;
}
```

I've used `Repository` as the generic type because the `ICache<T>` interface constraints the type to `Repository`.

Now the problem:
I've got a method to add a cache that looks like this

```
static void Add<TCache>(Repository repo)
    where TCache : Repository, ICache<TCache>
{
    ICache<TCache> newEntry = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TCache), repo) as ICache<TCache>;
    Caches.Add(newEntry); // Error: Cannot convert from ICache<TCache> to ICache<Repository>
}
```

That confuses me. From my understanding this should work because I've added the constraint `where TCache : Repository` to the method, so adding an item of that type
to a list of `ICache<Repository>` should work. It's the same constraint.

What's the problem here?

Comment: An `ICache<SomethingDerivedFromRepository>` *isn't* an `ICache<Repository>`, generally. Inheritance relationships don't automatically apply to generics parameterized on those types.

Comment: You can make `ICache<TRepo>` covariant using `out` i.e. `ICache<out TRepo>`. See similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62950178/8126362). Although you must declare `TRepo Repository` as `get` only.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Ah, I see. But in that case ```TRepo Repository { get; set; }``` would not work anymore - unless I remove the setter. But I also need that one. _edit_: Seems like I can still add the setter in the CarCache, didn't know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to make `ICache<TRepo>` covariant.

You would need to make `TRepo Repository` `get`-only to comply with covariant restrictions:

```
public interface ICache<out TRepo> where TRepo : Repository
{
    TRepo Repository { get; }
}
```

This would work fine as long as the property is only set via your constructor:

```
public class CarCache : CarRepository, ICache<CarRepository> 
{
    public CarRepository Repository { get; }

    public CarCache(CarRepository repo)
    {
        this.Repository = repo; // Fine to set Repository here
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or you could make the setter `private` to allow other methods of the implementation class to set the value:

```
public class CarCache : CarRepository, ICache<CarRepository> 
{
    public CarRepository Repository { get; private set; }

    // ...
    
    void SetRepository(CarRepository repo)
    {
        this.Repository = repo;
    }
}
```